# How to set a variable in SQLCMD mode after running a SQL statement?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I'm trying to lookup a variable in a SQL statement and then set a SQLCMD mode variable from that.  Something like this:

```
:setvar MYVARIABLE "1"

DECLARE @MYVARIABLE int
SELECT @MYVARIABLE=col1 FROM mytable WHERE ID=1

-- This line is wrong
SET $(MYVARIABLE) = @MYVARIABLE

SELECT * FROM another_table WHERE ID = $(MYVARIABLE)
```

I know I can just do this:

```
SELECT * FROM another_table WHERE ID = @MYVARIABLE
```

The problem is that there is some existing code that uses `$(MYVARIABLE)` that I'm trying not to touch.

How do I set $(MYVARIABLE) after running the SQL code?

Comment: You can't do that. The script runs in two phases. First: the SQLCMD stuff runs. Then the T-SQL runs. By the time @MYVARIABLE exists, MYVARIABLE does not.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use plain-old `cmd.exe`, you can do something like:

```
for /F "usebackq" %M in (`sqlcmd -S yourserver -d yourdatabase -E -W -h -1 -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON ; SELECT TOP (1) col1 FROM mytable WHERE ID = 1"`) do sqlcmd -S yourserver -d yourdatabase -E -v MYVARIABLE=%M -i TheRestOfYourScript.sql
```

To explain the `for` statement:

- `for` is a hack to do variable substition from `cmd.exe`.
- `/F` is the command-line switch for parsing.
- `"usebackq"` permits the backtick syntax that appears later.
- `%M` stores the output.  It needs to be just one letter.  If you end up putting the command in a .bat script, it needs to be `%%M` instead (or whatever other letter you choose).

To explain the first `sqlcmd` statement:

- `-S yourserver` and `-d yourdatabase` are probably the same as in your original `sqlcmd` invocation.
- `-E` is trusted authentication.  If you use some other means of authentication, replace `-E` with whatever you are using.
- `-W` eliminates leading and trailing whitespace from the result.
- `-h -1` eliminates the header row.
- `-Q` means "run this command and exit."

`SET NOCOUNT ON`, of course, prevents the`(1 row affected)` message, which you do not need to try to parse.

The second `sqlcmd` statement uses `-v MYVARIABLE=%M` to set the value within the script.  I believe that means you need not to have the `:setvar` command in your script, else you overwrite the command-line setting, but I could be wrong.